# My network disconnects and reconnects all the time

Tags: networking, ping

Every few minutes my internet connection fails and then reconnects automatically, though the Network indicator never changes. I can post some logs if needed, I just don't know what, any help would be highly appreciated.

While doing an infinite ping to Google, I get stable ping (50-60 ms), but after a while the ping just stops and continues after the connection is back.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to turn off the proprietary wireless adapter driver. To do so go to Software & Updates and check the Additional Drivers tab.

Comment: I'll try this in a while :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?